# how can I make my sql update statement work?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

My code won't update the database although I've tried changing every aspect of it to find the mistake please help I can print the set but I can't update and change it. I've tried `prepareStatement` and `createStatement`.

```java
public void update() throws SQLException {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
            "UPDATE main_table SET status=? WHERE ID=1"
        );
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not update data to the database " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: The SQL part looks off. Are you trying to set it to NULL? i.e.: `"UPDATE main_table SET status=NULL WHERE ID=1"`. If you are trying to set it to a question mark, put the question mark in single quotes like this: `'?'`.

Comment: Are you getting any Exception? Is there any record having ID=1?

Comment: Close your `PreparedStatement` (try-with-resources is your friend). You will need to close the `Connection` too (at some point) to make sure updates are committed

Answer (score 1):

I would also check your table for any constraints that might be stopping you, and while the code there looks to be functional we're not able to see your database connection.

But here's a working example that should hopefully highlight the cause of your issue

I have a **students** table

[image: table]

Then I **print out the table contents**

```java
public static void main(String[] args){

    /* Print only students who are 18 and over */
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/jdbc-example","root","password");
    String queryAges = "Select * from students where age >= ?";
    PreparedStatement agesStmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryAges);
    agesStmt.setInt(1, 18);
    ResultSet rs = agesStmt.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.printf("ID: %d, Name: %s, Age: %d\n",
            rs.getInt("id"),
            rs.getString("name"),
            rs.getInt("age"));
    }
    rs.close();
    agesStmt.close();
    conn.close();

}
```

Output

```
ID: 1, Name: Henry Holt, Age: 47
ID: 2, Name: Barry McLarry, Age: 32
ID: 5, Name: Gail Emmerson, Age: 24
```

**Update a student's age then print that student record**

```java
public static void main( String[] args ) throws SQLException {

    /* Change Henry's age to 48 */
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/jdbc-example", "root", "password");
    String queryAges = "update students set age = ? where (name = ?)";
    PreparedStatement updateStmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryAges);
    updateStmt.setInt(1, 48);
    updateStmt.setString(2, "Henry Holt");
    int status = updateStmt.executeUpdate();
    if (status == 1) {
        PreparedStatement fetch = conn.prepareStatement("select * from students where name = ?");
        fetch.setString(1, "Henry Holt");
        ResultSet rs = fetch.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next())
            System.out.printf("ID: %d, Name: %s, Age: %d\n",
                    rs.getInt("id"),
                    rs.getString("name"),
                    rs.getInt("age"));
        rs.close();
    }
    updateStmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

Output

```
ID: 1, Name: Henry Holt, Age: 48
```

I hope that's helpful

Answer (score 0):

Is the column `status` accepting `NULL` value in the table `main_table`? You can't input `NULL` value, in a column that not alow it

Comment: either the status column can become null or not(I tried both) it still wont run and I am not getting an exception. it just won't change the value.

Comment: Try to check if there are any rows getting updated


`updateCount = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();`